# How to expand $\ln(A+\delta A) $ to the second order in $\delta A$?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Let $A$ be a strictly positive matrix, that is, $A$ is Hermitian and all its eigenvalues are positive. I would like to know how to expand
\begin{eqnarray}
\ln(A+\delta A)
\end{eqnarray}
to the second order in $\delta A$. Here, $\delta A$ is a variation of $A$ and is required to be Hermitian.

Comment: Hint: Diagonalize

Comment: Both $A$ and $\delta A$ are diagonalized but possibly in different bases. So, this is why the question is nontrivial.

Comment: *Better Hint*: Baker-Campbell-Hausdorff formula and its dual the Zassenhaus formula.